# Trying To Use Electron With NuxtJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nuxt.js

I've followed these steps to [create a nuxt/electron project](https://github.com/soulehshaikh99/create-nuxt-electron-app), And it worked perfectly... But once I tried to use any of electron's modules like the ipcRenderer in a component or page, it doesn't work. The problem is at:

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
```

I tried running the above code snippet and I got the following error:

```js
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\DELL\Programming\JavaScript\Electronjs\create-nuxt-electron-app\node_modules\electron'
```

I've turned "nodeIntegration" on (although I prefer not), And it's still not working.

Hope someone who has done this before can help

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I'he tried everything suggested, changed webpack config target to `electron-renderer` , used `const {ipcRenderer} = eval('require')('electron') , even added` preload.js` to my app and in preload.js added this piece of code:

```js
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

but still in page.vue couldn't access `ipcRenderer` . So I changed my boilerplate to [electron-nuxt](https://github.com/michalzaq12/electron-nuxt) and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks man, I will try that too.

Comment: @user11836845 Oh btw, as I had some issue with Prisma on that boilerplate, so changed to Nuxtron boilerplate , https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nuxtron . but beside prisma , that boilerplate works just fine and is more recent than nuxtron